# Use angular ui bootstrap carousel only on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

Is there any way to apply the bootstrap carousel only conditionally for mobile devices and use it's content as static html for desktop?

I've the specification **to have no duplicated html** to display the same content differently for mobile and desktop (defined by the respective bootstrap breakpoint definitions and the devices width). That's why I can't just use two different containers for the content. In the design there is a carousel given for mobile whose content should be displayed as static html for desktop.

Comment: how do you define a "mobile device"? if the viewport is small enough ? how about adding a watcher for view port width and when it's small enough you use `ng-if` to show whatever you need.

Comment: good question: I would define it by device width with the breakpoint $screen-sm

Answer (score 0):

UI-Bootstrap doesn't handle conditionally showing ui components, but plain ol' angular do, you can write a directive that watches for screen size and resize events and updates a value accordingly, then use an `ng-if` with that value.

1. bind a value to the resize event and run `$apply()` when width changes
2. attach a watch to `$window.innerWidth` and listen to it's values, when apply will run the watch will test if the width is bigger or smaller than 768 px.

   ```
   // inside directive
   app.directive('viewPortWatcher', function($window) {
   return {
      restrict: "AE",
      scope: {
         show: "="
      },
      link: function(scope, element) {

       var width = angular.element($window);
       width.bind('resize', function() {
         scope.$apply();
       });

       scope.$watch(function() {
         return $window.innerWidth;
       }, function(value) {
         if (value <= 768) { // sm
           scope.show = true;
         } else {
           scope.show = false;
         }
       });
     }
   }
   }
   ```
3. in your html

   ```
   <view-port-watcher show="show"></view-port-watcher>

   <span ng-if="show">
     show carousel 
   </span> 
   <span ng-if="!show">
     don't show carousel 
   </span>
   ```

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ySu0F8TgeMiWyVkcurZj?p=preview)

Comment: While I would use this approach for other things, in this case I would say that using css breakpoints is a much better solution.

Comment: basically that's what my approach does at `if (value <= 768) { // sm`, because angular isn't aware of these breakpoints I had to hardcode these values.